# How to make EditText not editable through XML in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can anyone tell me how to make an `EditText` not editable via XML? I tried setting `android:editable` to `false`, but

1. it is deprecated; and
2. it didn't work.

Comment: If not editable, why would you need the EditText? Wont using an ordinary TextView be enough? And is setEditable() function deprecated too?

Comment: For me this makes sense in order to enable standard copy paste for the contents. With a TextView it's not possible (at least not default behaviour)

Comment: Correction: It's a bad idea. On certain circunstances the view becomes editable, or the copy paste options doesn't show anymore. Will look for other approach.

Comment: In my case, I want to temporarily disable an EditText while a set of operations performs, and then reenable it when the operation finishes.

Comment: This question is about a legitimate concern. To preserve the `EditText` style and permit scrolling, use `UI.setReadOnly(myEditText, true)` from [this library](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib). There are a few properties that have to be set, which you can check out [in the source code](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-BaseLib/blob/62299c79d100e38627600907e755d563de072234/Source/src/im/delight/android/baselib/UI.java#L264).

Comment: @kiki: TextView elements are not as big as EditText.

Comment: Linking this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470171/edittext-not-editable

Answer (score 413, accepted):

Use this simple code:

```
textView.setKeyListener(null);
```

It works.

**Edit : To add `KeyListener` later, do following**

1 : set key listener to tag of `textView`

```
textView.setTag(textView.getKeyListener());
textView.setKeyListener(null);
```

2 : get key listener from tag and set it back to `textView`

```
textView.setKeyListener((KeyListener) textView.getTag());
```

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi textView.setTag(textView.getKeyListener()); set it back later with textView.setKeyListener((KeyListener)textView.getTag());

Comment: @TomDignan great way easily to that! I do have one question. Does this in any way change the default values needed by KeyListener, like `setFocusable()` because the doc says that the default implementation might be changed if changed.

Comment: afaik no, the tag should be available for you to use

Comment: It works, but softkeyboard does not show "Next" key which would easily navigate focus to next editable text. How would you fix that?

Comment: I would suggest to edit XML file and set :

    `android:enabled="false"`

Comment: Good solution for when you need EditText as is (i.e. focusable and clickable) but are using something other than keyboard to enter characters. +1

Comment: The question was about setting it via *XML*, why is this marked as solution?

Comment: Completely agree with this answer.
However, the EditText's cursor disappeared with this method on my side.
I also toggled the cursor visibility ending with this code:

Disabling: 

`editText.setCursorVisible(false);`

`editText.setTag(editText.getKeyListener());`

`editText.setKeyListener(null);`

Enabling: 

`editText.setKeyListener((KeyListener) editText.getTag());`

`editText.setCursorVisible(true);`

Answer (score 415):

Add this to your EditText xml file:

```
<EditText ...
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:cursorVisible="false" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
</EditText>
```

It will do the same effect as `android:editable="false"`. Worked for me, hope it'll work for you too.

Comment: notes.setKeyListener(null);
notes.setClickable(false);
notes.setCursorVisible(false);
notes.setFocusable(false);
notes.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

Comment: If you want to do it in the XML ... what will be the difference between it and TextView ???

Comment: The difference is It can be used with `TextInputLayout`

Comment: Keep in mind your EditText won't be usable by keyboards or D-Pads if you set it not focusable.

Comment: This should be marked as the solution, as it is a pure XML solution as requested in the question.

Comment: After use all of the answer to given this question . **This one be perfectly worked for me .**

Comment: It might work, but it won't do the same effect as `editable="false"`. This setting doesn't disable focus or clickability. If I try to set listeners for when the EditText is focused/clicked, but I don't want to allow the user to manually edit it?

Comment: It's still has flaw, confirmed on device Redmi, by repeating tap, can still show up select-copy-paste mini-dialog. Add `enabled=false` to resolve it.

Comment: There is not a better way?, Why change 1 line to 4. Because in older version the xml annotation `android:editable = false` did it.

Comment: this worked for me, and to make it like a clickable. I just removed `android:clickable="false"` from your solution to do the editing on another fragment/acitivity.

Comment: This is deprecated (October 2018)

Comment: That does NOT has the same effect as setting editable to false, with the last you can still click on the control and select and copy its contents.

Answer (score 55):

Let your Edittext be

```
EditText editText;
```

`editText.setKeyListener(null);`

will work but it just not listening to keys.

User can see a cursor on the edittext.

You can try `editText.setEnabled(false);`

That means user cannot see the cursor. To simply say it will became `TextView`.

Comment: It's correct since EditText is a subclass of TextView. However,  please use editText as a variable instead of textView.

Comment: @JoePlante Changed variable name thanks for constructive comment.

Comment: this grays out the EditText

Comment: Grayed EditText indicates that its is disabled and user can't edit it.

Comment: Settting the colour as well as will prevent the grayed appearance. XML: Try        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:enabled="false"

Comment: @Redwine yes, that could work. IMO, gray out convey item in disabled state. If at all the EditText will be enabled based on another action (a button click?), user will come to know the correlation between those UI components.

Answer (score 34):

As mentioned in other answers, you can do a `setEnabled(false)`  but since you are asking how to set it via XML, here is how to do it.

Add the following attribute to your `EditText`:

```
android:enabled="false"
```

Comment: exact answer to the OPs question.

Comment: but this method deprecated

Comment: @Lalitkumar `enabled` is not deprecated. `editable` is.

Comment: by enable, we cant access the click listener as well. so for me its not the answer.

Comment: this is hide text :(

Answer (score 25):

disable from XML (one line):

```
 android:focusable="false"
```

re-enable from Java, if need be (also one line):

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: Good Answer. This way you can still set editText value using editText.setText("your text"). But user can't edit it.

Answer (score 19):

They made "editable" deprecated but didn't provide a working corresponding one in inputType.

By the way, does inputType="none" has any effect? Using it or not does not make any difference as far as I see.

For example, the default editText is said to be single line. But you have to select an inputType for it to be single line. And if you select "none", it is still multiline.

Comment: It does not make a difference on _all_ devices, but it _should_, according to the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType(int)

Comment: A beautiful example of Google mess

Answer (score 15):

This combination worked for me:

```
<EditText ... >
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 13):

As you mentioned android:editable is deprecated. android:inputType="none" should be used instead but it does not work due to a bug (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2854)

But you can achieve the same thing by using focusable.

Via XML:

```
<EditText ...
        android:focusable="false" 
</EditText>
```

From code:

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.LoginNameEditText)).setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: Courtesy of google, the bug will fall into two different scenario:
1.) It will be fix but after 6 years
2.) It will never be fix, they'll just develop new version of Android.

Answer (score 13):

if you want to click it, but not want to edit it, try:

```
        android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 9):

Just use  `android:enabled="false"`. This will also give an appearance to the `EditText` which will make it look not editable.

Answer (score 7):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtDate"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

and use following :

```
txtDate.setKeyListener(null);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it in java code just use this line to disable it:

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

And this to enable it:

```
editText.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried to do:

```
textView.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_NULL );
```

which should work, but for me it did not.

I finished with this code:

```
textView.setKeyListener(new NumberKeyListener() {
    public int getInputType() {
        return InputType.TYPE_NULL;
    }

    protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
        return new char[] {};
    }
});
```

which works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

When I want an activity to not focus on the EditText and also not show keyboard when clicked, this is what worked for me.

Adding attributes to the main layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and then the EditText field

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_landing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="com.woppi.woppi.samplelapp.HomeActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/fromEditText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/placeholder_choose_language"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="onSelectFromLanguage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @mahe madi
you can try this as well

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
editor.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

This method will hide cursor, lose focus and more importantly set text color to black behaving like TextView.

And to revert Back to editText simply do this to gain all the properties of EditText.

```
editText.setEnabled(true);
```

Hope it Helps :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `android:editable="false"` but I would really advise you 
to use `setEnabled(false)` as it provides a visual clue to the user that 
the control cannot be edited. The same visual cue is used by all 
disabled widgets and consistency is good.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
android:inputType="none"
```

Answer (score 3):

This way did the job for me, i can selec and copy to clipboard, but i can't modify or paste.

```
android:enable="true"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
android:inputType="none"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the following:

```
codeEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

this.codeEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    if (hasFocus) {

      pickCode();

    }

  }

});
this.codeEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    pickCode();

  }

});
```

but the problem was that if the edit text is the first in the form then
it gets the focus and the pickCode() code which launches a new activity
is called straight away. So I modified the code as follows and it seems
to work quite well (except I cannot set the focus on the text edit but
I don't need to):

```
itemCodeEditText.setFocusable(false);

this.itemCodeEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    pickItem();

  }

});
```

Best Regards,

Comments welcome,

John Goche

Comment: Seems to work fine, but isn't it easier to use TextView which looks like EditText (using : style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" ) ?

Answer (score 2):

I use `EditText.setFocusable(false)` and set true again if I want to edit.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this!, it may help some people

```
<EditText  
android:enabled="false"
android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 1):

**android:editable** is deprecated so use **inputType** instead.

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_x"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:hint="@string/enter_x" />
```

Comment: android:inputType="none" is much different from android:editable, try it yourself!

Comment: If you're going to make your EditText non-editable, may I suggest using the TextView widget instead of the EditText, since using a EditText seems kind of pointless in that case.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't apply for an EditText with a PopupWindow, see [this image](http://i.imgur.com/h2D37xJ.png) to better understand the problem. In this example I do want the look of an EditText but I have to "lock it" in order to let the user change the value just by the popupwindow. [Check this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187185) to see more motivation. It's a problem that is around since 2009.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem but after observation I found that `android:editable="false"` is only working when inputtype (`android:inputType="ANY_VALUE"`) is **not** given in the Edittext.

Remove inputType from EditText and use editable = false, its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** 
I used `android:focusable="false"` and it worked. Click listening is also working now.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this with a dialog.

```
    AlertDialog dialog;
    EditText _editID;
    TextView _txtID;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        _txtID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id._txtID);
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        _editID = new EditText(this);
        _editID.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
        dialog.setTitle("Numero do Registro:");
        dialog.setView(_editID);
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "IR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                _txtID.setText(_editID.getText());
                toId(Integer.parseInt((_editID.getText().toString())));
            }
        });
        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        _txtID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _txtID.setText("_editID.getText()");
                //_editID.setText("");
                dialog.show();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin extension option:

```
fun AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.setEditable(editable: Boolean) {
    if (!editable) {
        this.tag = this.keyListener
        this.keyListener = null
    } else {
        if(this.tag is KeyListener) {
            this@setEditable.keyListener = this@setEditable.tag as KeyListener
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle between editable of edittext by this method:

```
public void toggleEditableOfEditText(EditText editText){
        if (editText.getKeyListener() != null) {
            editText.setTag(editText.getKeyListener());
            editText.setKeyListener(null);
        } else {
            editText.setKeyListener((KeyListener) editText.getTag());
        }
    }
```

and then use this method to make edittext editable or not editable:

```
toggleEditableOfEditText(editText);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Answer (score -10):

Try this code. It's working in my project, so it will work in your project.

```
android:editable="false"
```

Comment: I can confirm that this not works and what's more using depreciated method is not recommended.

Comment: android:editable is actually the best solution if you want the field to be clickable but not editable, i.e. to open a dialog after clicking on it.

Comment: not because it works on your project it will on ours. Very poor thinking.