# EditText non editable

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make an EditText non editable with this code:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/outputResult"
          android:inputType="text"
          android:editable="false"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/result" />
```

I had to add following line to make it non-editable

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: know why does not work only with android:editable="false". Thanks.

Comment: @Zortkun: That is exactly what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Jjreina: My guess is that it's because you're specifying an `inputType` and that may be overriding the `android:editable="false"` setting. I may be wrong though.

Comment: MisterSquonk i remove inputType and work fine but show warnig This text field does not specify an inputType or a hint                   Thanks you very much.                                                 Now I had add android:inputType="none" and all ok, Thanks all

Answer (score 205, accepted):

`android:editable="false"` should work, but [it is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#editable), you should be using `android:inputType="none"` instead.

Alternatively, if you want to do it in the code you could do this :

```
EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
mEdit.setEnabled(false);
```

This is also a viable alternative :

```
EditText mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
mEdit.setKeyListener(null);
```

If you're going to make your `EditText` non-editable, may I suggest using the `TextView` widget instead of the `EditText`, since using a EditText seems kind of pointless in that case.

**EDIT:** Altered some information since I've found that `android:editable` is deprecated, and you should use `android:inputType="none"`, but there is a bug about it on android code; So please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6174440/421467).

Comment: Thanks with alternative work tine but android:editable="false" no

Comment: Use of textview is better in this case

Comment: The below answer of setting `android:enabled="false"` works better if you also want the input to be greyed out.

Comment: `android:inputType="none"` still allows you to type text

Comment: Agree with @user924 . `android:inputType="none"` still allows user to type text with another solution. (e.g, hardware keyboard)

Comment: You can use a `TextView` like others have said, but set the style of it to be the `EditText` style.

Answer (score 35):

I guess I am late but use following together to make it work:

```
 android:inputType="none"
 android:enabled="false"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using `android:inputType="none"` won't be what you are expecting unless you add `android:enabled="false"`

Comment: This. Setting just either inputType="none" or enabled="false" doesn't seem to do anything.. must be both!

Answer (score 18):

In case you want to make an EditText not editable from code:

```
void disableInput(EditText editText){
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    editText.setTextIsSelectable(false);
    editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v,int keyCode,KeyEvent event) {
                return true;  // Blocks input from hardware keyboards.
        }
    });
}
```

In case you want to remove the horizontal line of your EditText, just add:

```
editText.setBackground(null);
```

If you want to let users copy the content of the EditText then use:

```
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Answer (score 11):

```
 <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editTexteventdate"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="Date of Event"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:editable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"

            />
```

> Add this

android:editable="false"

android:focusable="false"

android:clickable="false"

**its work for me**

Comment: Since editable is deprecated use this instead: `                android:inputType="none"`(along with the other ones you have).

Comment: Not because it works for you it should work for us as well. You posted this on May 19th of this year so you must be aware you provided a deprecated answer? C'mon...

Comment: User is still able to use `paste` option to change text of the `EditText`.

Answer (score 9):

well `android:editable="false"` is deprecated and doesn't work anymore and `android:inputType="none"` would not give you the results you want

you could use

```
<EditText
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:maxLength="10"/>
```

and if you want to make the EditText editable again you could do that with code

```
//enable view's focus event on touch mode
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

//enable cursor is visible
edittext.setCursorVisible(true);

// You have to focus on the edit text to avoid having to click it twice
//request focus 
edittext.requestFocus();

//show keypad is used to allow the user input text on the first click
InputMethodManager openKeyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

openKeyboard.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Note I'm using `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` and not

```
android:focusable="false"
```

because when I use

```
edittext.setFocusable(true);
```

I still have to add

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Like this

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edittext.setFocusable(true);
```

for the edittext focus to be enabled again

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to use an editText and not a textView, then consider using these three:

```
android:focusable="false"

android:clickable="false"

android:longClickable="false"
```

EDIT: The "longClickable" attribute disables the long press actions that cause the "Paste" and or "Select All" options to show up as a tooltip.

Answer (score 3):

Add below line in youe xml edittext.

```
android:editable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Its working for me

Answer (score 3):

### Use This:

```
EditText edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
edtText.setEnabled(false);
```

and you can use `android:enabled` property in your xml file as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
android:enabled = false
```

Include that line in your layout xml file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your disabled EditText to look the same as your enabled one, you should use `android:enabled="false"` in combination with `android:textColor="..."`.

Here is an example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        ...
        android:text="..."
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your edit text clickable but not editable, You can try this:

```xml
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:inputType="none"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: Used this if you have an icon to be clickable, this  works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, too.

I did this:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/yourid"
    android:editable="false"
    android:inputType="none" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:inputType="none"
android:enabled="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

The clickable attribute is **optional**! You can still **set text** to the edit text **programmatically**!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to achieve an edit text behavior in Andorid TV were you need to make a non editable edit text but clickable, the below method helps you to achieve that -

```
/**
 * Disable edit text input skill
 */
    fun EditText.disableInput() {
        showSoftInputOnFocus = false
        keyListener = null // Make non editable
        // Hide keyboard when disabled edittext gets focus
        setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) hideKeyboard()
        }
    }

fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

You can get the click event using the conventional `onClick` listener thereafter

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to have an edittext look and feel and to open a pop up window on its click, but making enabled as false will not allow click listener on it. So I did it in this way.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tvCustomerAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_down"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        tools:text="24"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get rid of **SoftKeyboard** for the used `EditText` in the *Tablet version* and the following code snippet did the job very well.

```
eText.setEnabled(false);
eText.setFocusable(false);
eText.setActivated(false);
eText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this attribute in your edittext.

```
<EditText
         android:editable="false"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

If not necessary, try removing the inputType attribute. `android:editable="false"` works fine.