# How to make an Edittext not clickable

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make an Editext only focus when I programmably tell it to and not allow the user to press on the one he wants.  Is this possible?

I tried

> ```
> android:longClickable="false"
> android:clickable="false"
> ```

But neither worked.

For some reason people are thinking the following solves my problem, but that person is trying to make an edit text not editable, where I am trying to make an edit text only not focusable by clicking

[EditText not editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470171/edittext-not-editable)

Comment: try adding `focusable`  false and see

Comment: Try setting `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` to false

Answer (score 8):

Try with

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by using:

```
.setEnabled(false) and .setClickable(false)
```

so use this for your code:

```
.setEnabled(false);
.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: it still stealing clicks from the parent so it is still technically clickable even when it is not doing anything

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever got this answered, but I had to do the same thing and although this may not be concise, I know it works:

First set the keyListener to null:

```
myEditText.setKeyListener(null);
```

Next set an OnTouch listener to the EditText to do whatever action you want:

```
myEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    //Do whatever action you need to do here. 
                }
                return false;
            }
});
```

From there, you can simply insert your actions into the OnTouch listener ACTION_UP action tag. In my case, I needed to popup a Dialog with a listview for them to choose something and then set the respective text into the EditText.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

**PROGRAMATICALLY**

I ran into the same issue and solved it by using:

```
.setEnabled(false), .setClickable(false) and .setFocuseable(false)
```

so use this for your code:

```
et.setEnabled(false);
et.setClickable(false);
et.setFocuseable(false);
```

**USING XML**

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);
et.setFocusable(false);
et.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: It doesnt allow programically changing it

Answer (score 0):

Immediate parent of the EditText should  steal the focus.For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enter.." />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.isEnabled = false // makes it`s color grey
editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#DE000000")) //change color if needed
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to use this line

```
        android:inputType="none"
```

in your xml   this line will prevent keyboard from showing

Answer (score -1):

In the xml file try using the following code-

```
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

use it on the EditText. I haven't tried it but hope it works.

Comment: Doesnt do anything, i can still click to change focus

Comment: change to `focusableInTouchMode="false"`