# Android Studio:EditText editable is deprecated How to use inputType

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget

I want to realize

```
android:editable="false"
```

But it told me editable is *deprecated* ,you can use `inputType` instead.

So I don't know how to realize it by using `inputType`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470171/edittext-not-editable

Comment: you should try android:inputType="none"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText not editable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470171/edittext-not-editable)

Comment: FYI: I found on my app that when `inputType="none"`, it still showed a cursor on the field. I had to set `editable="false"` to make it go away, anyway.

Answer (score 21):

Use

> android:clickable="false"

. but In case you want to use onclick listener for it. don't use

> android:clickable="false"

.. Use

> android:cursorVisible="false" android:focusable="false" .

Answer (score 14):

## The Code

> In XML

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Hint"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    />
```

## The Result

[image]

## Java Code

You can achieve the same result at runtime with this code

```
EditText et = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
et.setFocusable(false);
et.setClickable(false);
et.setCursorVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using any input type that is not kind of text or number like date or date and time you can use `android:inputType="date"` or `android:inputType="datetime"` or `android:inputType="time"`. If you are not using any such kind of input type you can use `android:inputType="none"`.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above suggesting XML markup changes doesnt seem to work. However I managed to achieve a similar result through code.

Simply use:

editText.setKeyListener(null);

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you wanted to use click of edittext and disable input

```
android:clickable="false" 
android:cursorVisible="false" 
android:focusable="false" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control behavior of EditText from TextWatcher

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(String text) {
     setEditTextCurrentValue((isEditTextEditable())?text:getEditTextCurrentValue());
}
```

So user can enter to the control, can copy its content. But he can't change it if you forbid.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:inputType="none"
```

instead of

```
android:editable="false"
```

Comment: this does nothing, still able to enter text

Answer (score 0):

well input type doesn't work the way you expect it to work when you use inputType=none

but you could use this to make your editText not editable which is what I think you want to achieve

```
<EditText
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:maxLength="10"/>
```

and if you want to make the EditText editable again you could do that with code

```
//enable view's focus event on touch mode
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

//enable cursor is visible
edittext.setCursorVisible(true);

// You have to focus on the edit text to avoid having to click it twice
//request focus 
edittext.requestFocus();

//show keypad is used to allow the user input text on the first click
InputMethodManager openKeyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

openKeyboard.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Note I'm using `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` and not

```
android:focusable="false"
```

because when I use

```
edittext.setFocusable(true);
```

I still have to add

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Like this

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edittext.setFocusable(true);
```

for the edittext focus to be enabled again

Answer (score 0):

Can be set it in code like this:

```
myEditText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL
```