# Make EditText editable programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a layout with one textView and one EditText and a button. EditText is made as non editable in xml file. I want to make it enabled via code.

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
         />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:editable="false"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit"
        android:onClick="edit"
        android:id="@+id/btnName"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: do it like `editText.setEditable(true);`

Comment: Are you tried setFocusable or setEnabled?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660151/how-to-replicate-androideditable-false-in-code

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928711/how-to-make-edittext-not-editable-through-xml-in-android/6174440#6174440) answer

Comment: @ELITE: there no setEditable method for editText

Comment: @RobertBanyai: I have tried that too, still its not working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove `android:editable="false"` this line from android xml file as this method is deprecated in android. and use below code to do so.

- **Make `EditText` non editable using java code**

In `onCreate` of activity do the following after `setContentView()` method

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
text.setTag(text.getKeyListener());
text.setKeyListener(null);
```

- **And make it editable using following code**

  ```
  text.setKeyListener((KeyListener) textView.getTag());
  ```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: what is stacktrace of crash??

Answer (score 1):

hey instead of editable use `android:enabled="false"` and in code  `setEnabled(true)`

Comment: let me know the feedback

Comment: Hi Naveen, thanks for your valuable suggestion. But your suggestion wont work as per my requirement. I want the edittext not edittable initally, on click of an Imagebutton it need to turn as editable. As per your suggesion, initially it will be editable on loading itself.

Comment: try with this combination once, android:enabled="false" android:focusable="false" and in code setEnabled(true)