# Material design Spinner using TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox styling

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I am currently using Material Design TextInputLayout OutlinedBox as shown below:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/myEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Title"
                android:inputType="text"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I am trying to add a dropdown box `Spinner` under my TextInputEditText, and would like to keep the same styling: OutlinedBox.

I see that dropdowns seem to be supported in Material Design, [Material Design Text Fields](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#usage). As shown on here for the Area:

[image: As shown on here for the Area]

I am currently using a Spinner to generate the Dropdown.

```
        <Spinner
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown"
            android:id="@+id/option"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:dropDownWidth="match_parent" />
```

It doesn't seem possible to add a dropdown following the OutlinedBox design. Is there a library out there that would allow me to make this happen, or is there a better way to implement this within Material Design?

Comment: Did you find answer to this question? I'm facing the same issue. As mentioned here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004976/in-android-how-to-create-an-outlined-dropdown-menu-spinner-as-specified-by-th

Comment: Has anyone (google) provided this view yet?  Awesome for them to show it in the design docs, yet completely leave an implementation out of the sdk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that this document isn't showing a `Spinner` at all. I think it's showing a `TextInputLayout` with a dropdown icon.

In the [Anatomy section](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#anatomy), at the Icons subsection, it says

> **5. Dropdown icon**
>
> A dropdown arrow indicates that a text field has a nested selection component.

Now, *how* you provide the "nested selection component" I'm not sure...

Answer (score 37):

I am assuming you want to have an Exposed drop-down menu inside the `TextInputLayout` I had the same problem, what you can do is use `AutoCompleteTextView` inside your `TextInputLayout` as in the following in the `XML`. here's an example of how I approached the issue.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:paddingEnd="30dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location_city_black_24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />




        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Type"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >



            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

You will also need an item layout resource to populate the dropdown popup. The example below provides a layout that follows the Material Design guidelines.

res/layout/dropdown_menu_popup_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"/>
```

In your class add the following code depending on what you want.

```
String[] type = new String[] {"Bed-sitter", "Single", "1- Bedroom", "2- Bedroom","3- Bedroom"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(
                        this,
                        R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item,
                        type);

        AutoCompleteTextView editTextFilledExposedDropdown =
                findViewById(R.id.filled_exposed_dropdown);
        editTextFilledExposedDropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

incase this doesn't help kindly check Exposed Dropdown Menus in material design page.
[https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu/][1]

This is my first answer on stack overflow I hope it helps.

Comment: If you're using Kotlin and VIEW binding, when trying to set your adapter you might get a "Val cannot be reassigned". You'll need to use **as** like this: ` (binding?.editTextFilledExposedDropdown as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.setAdapter(adapter) `

Answer (score 20):

Just use the [**`TextInputLayout`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) included in the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) with the style **`Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu`**.

Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
      android:hint="Hint text"
      ...>

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/outlined_exposed_dropdown_editable"
        .../>
  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your response it seems to be good but now how can we (with this solution) display the dropdown menu and manage selection of item etc. ?

Comment: Actually, it exists starting `"com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0"`

Comment: @AkbolatSSS Yes, 1.1.0 is currently the latest stable version.

Comment: This works very well but, I have a problem that after selecting an option, the dropdown doesn't show all the options again, only the one selected. Would there be a way to prevent this and show all the options again?

Answer (score 10):

From the other answers, "AutoCompleteTextView" is the answer but it does not do the same as a spinner does.

Here is my solution. Just put normal edittext inside TextInputLayout and make this editText disabled for inputs. And put a 0dp,0dp spinner for normal spinner working.

Don't make spinner visibility=gone, because if it's gone, spinner listener does not work

layout.xml

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_down_pacific_blue"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:hint="şehir"
            android:inputType="none" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        tools:listitem="@layout/general_spinner_item" />
```

java code

set click listener to edittext for trigger spinner click

```
findViewById(R.id.editText).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
                    spinner.performClick();
                }
            });
```

in spinner listener, set edittext text from selected item,

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                selectedCity= (City) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                editText.setText(selectedCity.getScreenText());

                RDALogger.debug("selectedObject " + selectedCity);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

and the result view

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I am using the below material libs to get spinner

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

Here is my layout look like

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/select_wifi"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hintStyle"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/wifi">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                style="@style/textInputEdittext"
                android:inputType="none" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Check out this image for the spinner

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems like they actually use a TextInputLayout wrapping up an AutoCompleteTextView. Note that they are already the material Components theme [https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md].

See: 
https://material.io/design/components/menus.html#exposed-dropdown-menu
https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu/

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem using this:
in XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        style="@style/AppTheme.ExposedDropdownMenu"                        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/my_spinner_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

in code:

```
        layout.keyListener=null
        ArrayAdapter(it, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list).also { 
         adapter ->
            layout.setAdapter(adapter)
        }
```

Credits:[How to make EditText not editable through XML in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928711/how-to-make-edittext-not-editable-through-xml-in-android)

Answer (score 3):

You can check my [Medium article where I introduce a custom MaterialSpinner](https://cernilovsky.medium.com/material-spinner-combo-box-for-android-b400bf8ab9d) which supports two-way data binding and selection tracking. The resulting layout can look as simple as this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/selection_hint"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/selection_icon"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
    app:endIconMode="@{viewModel.items == null || viewModel.items.size() != 0 ? TextInputLayout.END_ICON_DROPDOWN_MENU : TextInputLayout.END_ICON_NONE}">

    <com.example.MaterialSpinner
        android:id="@+id/items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:items="@{viewModel.items}"
        app:selectedPosition="@={viewModel.selectedItemPosition}"
        app:emptyText="@string/selection_no_item_text" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: app:endIconMode="dropdown_menu"  for those who dont use data binding

Answer (score 3):

I know its too late to answer this question, but somebody like me stuck in issue like this or similar may find this very useful. Visit this [repo](https://github.com/Mamoon-Alhawamdeh/AmazingSpinner) its perfect solution as requested. This library support all material TextInputLayout styles. Thanks to **["Mamoon Al-hawamdeh"](https://github.com/Mamoon-Alhawamdeh)** for this amazing library.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All this answers are helpful but the one important note that is if you set `app:endIconMode` attribute, your Drop down menu not work.

Answer (score -1):

Just change `inputType` from "text" to "none"

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/myEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:inputType="none"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```