# Updating a TextView closes Spinner

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem that seems simple, but I've been unable to resolve.

I have a normal `TextView` and a normal `Spinner` with some items together in a normal `ConstraintLayout`.

Whenever I update the `TextView` the spinner closes, which is a problem since it's being updated per second since it is used as a timer.

I have no idea what's causing the issue. So far, what I have done is

- Tried to use a [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/Chronometer) instead of a `TextView`. Same issue except I don't have to do the UI timing/updates myself.
- Tried to set `android:focusable="false"` within the layout. Same issue.
- Rather than directly set the text, I tried it within `View.post`

```kotlin
    binding.lastUpdateTimer.post {
        binding.lastUpdateTimer.text = displayTime
        binding.lastUpdateTimer.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(76, 175, 80))
    }
```

None of these helped.

**How do I update a `TextView` without closing an open `Spinner`?**

The full layout for reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivateClientFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_poleNumber"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:hint="Pole Number"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/napTypeTIL">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_poleNumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/nap_spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:entries="@array/nap_types"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Location"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/lastUpdateChrono"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:background="#FFEB3B"
                android:paddingStart="4sp"
                android:paddingEnd="4sp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire Activity/Fragment code?

Comment: @dennisrufigill Maybe in a few hours. I trimmed down the Fragment code to be safe to post, but it seems to have resolved the issue. It's my code it turns out.

Comment: @dennisrufigill I've resolved it. It wasn't my code.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it was a side effect of having both `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to zero. I implemented [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65902184/3979290) (using a `TextInputLayout` as an alternative to the [lack of a Material Spinner](https://rmirabelle.medium.com/there-is-no-material-design-spinner-for-android-3261b7c77da8)).

The answer suggests using a normal `TextInputLayout` with an `EditText`. Instead of being editable though, it catches the touch input event to open a hidden (`0dp` width and height) spinner. Selecting an item sets the `EditText`'s value to that item, which makes it functionally a spinner.

This was the issue. For some reason, setting the spinner dimensions to zero makes it so the spinner closes on any UI update.

I resolved the issue by setting one of them (width, height also works) to `1dp`.

Comment: Great work. Happy Learning.